# QGIS - Batch Populating CSV Field Based on Selection

Tags: qgis

I have selected points from a csv file which fall within one polygon named 'DM', by using the 'select by location' tool.

Within the csv, there is a field named 'Dataset'. I want to populate the 'Dataset' column with 'DM' for all of the selected points. Is there a way to do that from opening the attribute table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be opening the field calculator

[image]

Then, clicking "only update selected features" and "Update existing field", select your desired field (Dataset) and putting the value you want to include (DM) wrapped in single quotes in the lefthand side window
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when using the CSV file. However I have worked around your solution and exported the CSV as a shp, then followed your solution. Good stuff.